# android - webview not showing css background-color

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a webview that I have to update at a constant interval. here is my code

```
future = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable()
{                   
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        handler.postAtFrontOfQueue(new Runnable()
        {                           
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Log.d("set " + count);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18) {
                    clearView();
                } else {
                    loadUrl("about:blank");
                }
                count++;
                final String html = "<div style=\"background-color: #7777FF; text-align : center; width : 100% ; height : 100%;\">" + count + "</div>"
                final String base = "<html><body style='margin:0;padding:0;'>" + html + "</body></html>";           
                loadData(base, "text/html", Encoding.UTF_8.toString()); 

            }
        });
    }
},0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

my problem is that the css property ' background-color: #7777FF; ' stops showing after the second call to the function. Any ideas on how I can fix that? I remove the clearing of the view than the count does not update. Any method that could get the html to update and keep all of it's properties would be awesome.

first time 
 [image: working]

third time

[image: not working]

I am getting these logs

```
06-24 09:53:36.853: D/WebView(30537): loadUrlImpl: called
06-24 09:53:36.863: D/webcore(30537):  CORE loadUrl: called
06-24 09:53:36.863: D/webkit(30537): Firewall not null
06-24 09:53:36.863: D/webkit(30537): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
06-24 09:53:36.873: I/GATE(30537): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it had to do with the way my view was getting measured. I changed the on measure code to this

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    final int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height;
    int desiredHeight = Math.round(width * RATIO);

    if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        height = heightSize;
    } else if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        height = Math.min(desiredHeight, heightSize);
    } else {
        height = desiredHeight;
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

and now it works as expected.